# Mixed Integer Linear Programming Using Python with Multiple Objectives Support

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am very new to this field. I am working on MILP type of problem, and I am using Python with Pyomo.
Pyomo is very easy to use when you are having Single Objective Model. but in my case.

it is solving a very complicated type of Model that requires multiple objectives. I have seen some ppl suggesting to add a weight an implement it as (10*objective1 + objective2) as now objective1 will have bigger weight that objective2, but that wont solve my problem, as I am trying to do is to Maximize objective 1 and Minimize Objective 2

I am not strict to use only Pyomo, but i would like to use something easy as Pyomo with the support of Multiple Objectives.

What should i Use.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-objective optimization example Pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742999/multi-objective-optimization-example-pyomo). Note that minimizing `−f` is the same as maximizing `f`.

Comment: I have read this before. I dont think that would solve the issue as you are adding multiple objective and only solving one at a time

Comment: You can always implement a weighted sum or a lexicographic approach. In any environment, including Pyomo. For the weighted sum multiply the coefficients by (-1) when changing the sense of a single objective.

Comment: Erwin, that will work in very narrow cases. Many cases will fail in this way.

Comment: No. These are widely used methods, for many different applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [PolySCIP](http://polyscip.zib.de/) for multi-criteria optimization. Another easy way to use multiple objectives is the [Python interface of Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/multiple_objectives.html).

I cannot give you a detailed answer because is quite broad and generic.